# Best way to handle nulls in Java?

Tags: java, null

I have some code that is failing because of NullPointerException.  A method is being called on the object where the object does not exist.

However, this led me to think about the best way to fix this.   Do I always code defensively for nulls so that I future proof code for null pointer exceptions, or should I fix the cause of the null so that it won't occur downstream.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why would you not "fix the cause of the null"?  Can you provide an example of why this isn't the only sensible choice?  Clearly, something must be pushing you away from the obvious.  What is it?  Why isn't fix the root cause your first choice?

Comment: Well fixing the "root cause" of the issue may help in the short term, but if the code is still not defensively checking for nulls and is reused by another process that may introduce a null, i would have to fix it again.

Comment: @Shaun F: If the code is broken, it's broken.  I don't get how it's possible for code to produce unexpected nulls and not get fixed.  Clearly, there's some "dumb management" or "political" stuff going on.  Or something that allows erroneous code to be somehow acceptable.  Can you explain how erroneous code is not getting fixed?  What's the political background that leads you to ask this question?

Comment: No it's actually much much simpler than that.  There are no politics around it.  There is data created and at times this can have nulls in it.  I can fix the data creation routine and leave the consumer vulnerable to later data creation that had nulls in it, or i can fix the consumer, with ugly defensive code, and be assured that I could care less what happens upstream.

Comment: @Shaun F If you're worried about inadequate reuse, you can add `@throws NullPointerException If paramx is null` to the method Javadoc comment.

Comment: "vulnerable to later data creation that had nulls in it" What does that even mean?  If "I can fix the data creation routine" then there is no further vulnerability.  I'm unable to understand what this "later data creation that had nulls in it" can possibly mean?  Buggy software?

Comment: Fix the caller.

Comment: @S.Lott, encapsulation and single responsibility. All your code doesn't "know" what all your other code does. If a class accepts Froobinators, it makes as few assumptions as possible about who created the Froobinator and how. It make come from "external" code, or it make just come from a different part of the code base. I'm not saying you shouldn't fix buggy code; but search "defensive programming" and you'll find what the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 45):

If null is a reasonable input parameter for your method, fix the method. If not, fix the caller. "Reasonable" is a flexible term, so I propose the following test: How should the method hande a null input? If you find more than one possible answer, then null is *not* a reasonable input.

Comment: It's really as simple as that.

Comment: Guava has some very nice helper methods making the null check as simple as `Precondition.checkNotNull(...)`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022319/null-check-error-message-as-is-null-or-was-null/3022334#3022334

Comment: My rule is to initialize everything to sensible defaults if possible and worry about null exceptions afterwards.

Comment: Thorbjørn: So it replaces an accidental NullPointerException with an intentional NullPointerException? In some cases, doing the early check might be useful or even necessary; but I fear lots of senseless boilerplate null checks that add little value and just make the program larger.

Comment: If null is not a reasonable input parameter to your method but calls of the method are likely to accidentally pass null (especially if the method is public), you may also want to have your method throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when given null.  This signals to callers of the method that the bug is in their code (rather than in the method itself).

Comment: @davidk01 null can be a sensible input...

Answer (score 21):

**Don't use null, use Optional**

As you've pointed out, one of the biggest problems with `null` in Java is that it can be used *everywhere*, or at least for all reference types.

It's impossible to tell that could be `null` and what couldn't be.

Java 8 introduces a much better pattern: `Optional`.

And example from Oracle:

```
String version = "UNKNOWN";
if(computer != null) {
  Soundcard soundcard = computer.getSoundcard();
  if(soundcard != null) {
    USB usb = soundcard.getUSB();
    if(usb != null) {
      version = usb.getVersion();
    }
  }
}
```

If each of these may or may not return a successful value, you can change the APIs to `Optional`s:

```
String name = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
    .flatMap(Soundcard::getUSB)
    .map(USB::getVersion)
    .orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

By explicitly encoding optionality in the type, your interfaces will be much better, and your code will be cleaner.

If you are not using Java 8, you can look at `com.google.common.base.Optional` in Google Guava.

A good explanation by the Guava team: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

A more general explanation of disadvantages to null, with examples from several languages: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2015/08/31/the-worst-mistake-of-computer-science/

---

**@Nonnull, @Nullable**

Java 8 adds these annotation to help code checking tools like IDEs catch problems. They're fairly limited in their effectiveness.

---

**Check when it makes sense**

Don't write 50% of your code checking null, particularly if there is nothing sensible your code can do with a `null` value.

On the other hand, if `null` could be used and mean something, make sure to use it.

---

Ultimately, you obviously can't remove `null` from Java. I strongly recommend substituting the `Optional` abstraction whenever possible, and checking `null` those other times that you can do something reasonable about it.

Comment: Normally, answers to four year old questions end up deleted due to low quality. Good job talking about how Java 8 (which didn't exist back then) can solve the problem.

Comment: but irrelevant to the original question of course. And what's to say the argument is indeed optional?

Comment: @jwenting It's completely relevant to the original question. The answer to "What's the best way to drive a nail with a screwdriver" is "Use a hammer instead of a screwdriver".

Comment: @jwenting, I think I covered that, but for clarity: is the argument is not optional, I typically wouldn't check for null. You will have 100 lines of null checking and 40 lines of substance. Check for null at the more public interfaces, or when null actually makes sense (i.e. the argument is optional).

Comment: @Paul Draper: While I agree in general with the Guava team's take on use null, this is not a nuanced use of optional it's hackey and not in good way.  I might also point out that the lucid article is junk. The mistake was making the null pointer exception an unchecked exception. see my answer.

Comment: @J-Boss, how, in Java, would you *not* have an unchecked `NullPointerException`? A `NullPointerException` can happen literally  *every time* you call an instance method in Java. You would have `throws NullPointerException` in nearly every single method ever.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to handle this, peppering your code with `if (obj != null) {}` is not ideal, it is messy, it adds noise when reading the code later during the maintenance cycle and is error prone, as it is easy to forget to do this boiler plate wrapping.

It depends on if you want the code to continue executing quietly or fail. Is the `null` an error or an expected condition.

**What is null**

In every defintion and case, [Null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null) represents the absolute lack of data. Nulls in databases represent the lack of a value for that column. a null `String` is not the same as an empty `String`, a null `int` is not the same thing as ZERO, in theory. In practice "it depends". Empty `String` can make a good `Null Object` implementation for the String class, for `Integer` it depends on the business logic.

**Alternatives are:**

1. The [`Null Object`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern. Create an instance of your object that represents the `null` state, and initialize all references to that type with a reference to the `Null` implementation. This is useful for simple value type objects that don't have a lot of references to other objects that could also be `null` and is expected to be `null` as a valid state.
2. Use Aspect Oriented tools to weave methods with a `Null Checker` aspect that prevents the parameters from being null. This is for cases where `null` is an error.
3. Use `assert()` not much better than the `if (obj != null){}` but less noise.
4. Use a Contract Enforcement tool such as [Contracts For Java](http://code.google.com/p/cofoja/). Same use case as something like AspectJ but newer and uses Annotations instead of external configuration files. Best of both works of Aspects and Asserts.

1 is the ideal solution when incoming data is known to be `null` and needs to be replaced with some default value so that upstream consumers won't have to deal with all the null checking boilerplate code. Checking against known default values will be more expressive as well.

2, 3, and 4 are just convenient alternative Exception generators to replace `NullPointerException` with something more informative, which is always and improvement.

**In the End**

`null` in Java is almost in all cases a logic error. You should always strive to eliminate the root cause of `NullPointerExceptions`. You should strive to not use `null` conditions as business logic. `if (x == null) { i = someDefault; }` just make the initial assigment to that default object instance.

Comment: If possible the null object pattern is the way to, it is the most graceful way to handle a null case. It's rare that you want a null to cause stuff to blow up in production!

Comment: @Richard: unless that `null` is unexpected then it is a true error, then everything should come to a complete halt.

Comment: Null in databases and in programming code is handled differently in one important aspect: In programming, `null == null` (even in PHP), but in Databases, `null != null` because in databases it represents an *unknown* value rather than "nothing". Two unknowns are not necessarily equal, while two nothings are equal.

Answer (score 8):

Adding null checks may make testing problematic. See this great lecture ...

Check out Google Tech talks lecture: "The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!" he talks about it around minute 24

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&list=PL693EFD059797C21E

Paranoid programming involves adding null checks everywhere.
Seems like a good idea at first however from a testing perspective, 
it makes your null check type testing hard to deal with.

Also, when you create a precondition for the existence of some object
such as

```
class House(Door door){

    .. null check here and throw exception if Door is NULL
    this.door = door
}
```

it prevents you from creating House since you will be throwing an exception. Assume your test cases are creating mock objects for testing something other than Door, well, you can't do this because door is required

Those who have suffered through Mock creation hell are well aware of these types of annoyances.

In summary, your test suite should be robust enough to test for Doors, Houses ,Roofs
or whatever without having to be paranoid about it. Seroiusly, how difficult is it to add a null check test for specific objects in your testing :)

You should always prefer applications that work because you have several tests that PROVE it works, rather than HOPING it works simply because you have a whole bunch of preconditional null checks all over the place

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** - it is GOOD to check for unexpected `null`s but BAD for an application to try to make them good.

**Details**

Clearly, there are situations where `null` is a valid input or output to a method, and others where it is not.

*Rule #1:*

> The javadoc for a method that allows a `null` parameter or returns a `null` value *must* clearly document this, and explain what the `null` means.

*Rule #2:*

> An API method should not be specified as accepting or returning `null` unless there is a good reason to do so.

Given a clear specification of a method's "contract" vis-a-vis `null`s, it is a *programming error* to pass or return a `null` where you shouldn't.

*Rule #3:*

> An application should not attempt to "make good" programming errors.

If a method detects a `null` that shouldn't be there, it should not attempt to fix the problem by turning it into something else.  That just hides the problem from the programmer.  Instead, it should allow the NPE to happen, and cause a failure so that the programmer can figure out what the root cause is and fix it.  Hopefully the failure will be noticed during testing.  If not, that says something about your testing methodology.

*Rule #4:*

> Where feasible, write your code to detect programming errors early.

If you've got bugs in your code that result in lots of NPEs, the hardest thing can be figuring out where the `null` values came from.  One way to make diagnosis easier is to write your code so that the `null` is detected as soon as possible.  Often you can do this in conjunction with other checks; e.g.

```
public setName(String name) {
    // This also detects `null` as an (intended) side-effect
    if (name.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty name");
    }
}
```

(There are obviously cases where rules 3 and 4 should be tempered with reality.  For instance (rule 3), some kinds of applications *must* attempt to continue after detecting probably programming errors.  And (rule 4) too much checking for bad parameters can have a performance impact.)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend fixing the method to be defensive.  For instance:

```
String go(String s){  
    return s.toString();  
}
```

Should be more along the lines of this:

```
String go(String s){  
    if(s == null){  
       return "";  
    }     
    return s.toString();  
}
```

I realize this is absolutely trivial, but if the invoker expects an object give them a default object that won't cause a null to be passed around.

Comment: +1 That's something I've never thought about, and certainly has merit.

Comment: This has a nasty side-effect in that the caller (programmer who codes against this API) might develop a habit of passing null as a parameter to get "default" behavior.

Comment: @Goran Correct, that is why one must be careful when creating an API you only get one shot to get it right

Comment: If this is Java, you shouldn't be using `new String()` at all.

Comment: @biziclop changed just for you :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo I have an eye for the truly important. :)

Comment: @biziclop actually it is far more important than most realize.

Comment: @Michael, never thought of?  Happens much, much too frequently when using other peoples code...

Comment: @Thorbjorn my pattern happens too much?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Not sure I understand you. Are you talking NIH or that I hadn't seen it before?

Comment: @Goran, in the JavaDoc just mention that "behaviour for null as an argument is undefined".

Comment: @Michael, just a bit surprised that you hadn't seen it before.  I believe this to be too small for NIH.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, no that your code is called by somebody else and there is a null somewhere.  You tend to get VERY defensive.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Neat! Thanks for that trick

Comment: In my opinion it makes more sense to place an assert and throw an exception if the argument is null, since it's clearly the caller's mistake. Don't silently "fix" caller mistakes; instead, make them aware of them.

Comment: @AndresF. asserts only work if you enable them

Comment: @Woot4Moo So write your own code that throws an exception then. The important thing is to inform the caller that their passed arguments are wrong, and tell them as soon as possible. Silently correcting `null`s is the worst possible option, worse than throwing an NPE.

Comment: @AndresF. it isn't silently correcting a null pointer, it is returning a safe value for an invocation that could be damaging to the system.

Comment: @Woot4Moo No, that's the wrong approach. You are silently correcting an NPE because you are letting the caller indistinctly use `""` or `null`, which is almost *never* the right course of action. If you do this, you should also write in your javadoc `"be aware the API treats "" and null indistinctly"`, at which point you must just as well simply write "null is an error" and throw an exception. Clients calling your code will become aware of the problem the first time they try using a `null`, so what's the big deal. And if they are *accidentally* passing null, then it's an ERROR in THEIR CODE.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Your API must never try to silence errors in the client's code. You are doing them a disservice. On the contrary, the API must bring errors to the caller's attention, which in turn will help them correct their own code. Consider this alternate scenario: division by zero is always an error. What would happen if your code silently corrected a `0` to a `1` in order to save the caller the effort of dealing with a division by zero error? Hiding caller errors under the rug is almost never the right course of action.

Comment: I work with a codebase that has a ton of methods that silently ignores NPEs and returns something "default" instead. This is basically the same thing as wrapping stuff in `catch (Exception)` and then just returning whatever. You're taking control away from the client and prevents them from finding bugs related to null values being passed.

Answer (score 2):

The following general rules about null have helped me a lot so far :

1. If the data comes from outside your control, systematically check for nulls and act appropriately.  This means either throwing an exception that makes sense to the function (checked or unchecked, just make sure the name of the exception tells you exactly what is going on.).  But NEVER lest a value loose in your system that can potentially carry surprises.
2. If Null is within the domain of appropriate values for your data model, deal with it appropriately.
3. When returning values try to not return nulls whenever possible.  Always prefer Empty lists, empty strings, Null Object patterns.  Keep nulls as returned values when this is the best possible representation of data for a given use case.
4. Probably the most important of all...  Tests, tests and test again.  When testing your code do not test it as a coder test it as a Nazi psychopath dominatrix and try to imagine all sorts of ways to torture the hell out of that code.

This tends a bit on the paranoid side regarding nulls often leading to façades and proxies that interface systems to the outside world and strictly controlled values in the inside with abundant redundancy.  The outside world here means pretty much everything I did not code myself. It does bear a cost runtime but so far I rarely had to optimize this by creating "null safe sections" of code.  I must say though that I mostly create long running systems for health care and the last thing I want is the interface subsystem carrying your iodine allergies to the CT scanner crashes because of an unexpected null pointer because someone else in another system never realized that names could contain apostrophes or characters like 但耒耨。

anyways.... my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

I would propose using Option/Some/None pattern from functional languages. I am not a Java specialist, but I intensively use my own implementation of this pattern in my C# project, and I am sure it could be converted into Java world.

The idea behind this pattern is: if it is logically to have situation when there is possibility of absense of a value (for example when retreiving from database by id) you provide an object of type Option[T], where T is a possible value. I case of absense of a value object of class None[T] returned, in case if existence of the value - object of Some[T] returned, containing the value.

In this case, you **must** handle possibility of value absence, and if you do code review you could easily found placec of incorrect handling. To get an inspiration from C# language implementation refer to my bitbucket repository https://bitbucket.org/mikegirkin/optionsomenone

If you return a null value, and it is logically equivalent an to error (for example no file exists, or could not connect) you should throw an exception, or use another error-handling pattern. The idea behind this, again, you end up with solution, when you **must** handle the situation of value absence, and could easily find the places of incorrect handling in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if one of the possible outcomes of your method is a null value then you should code defensively for that, but if a method is supposed to return a non-null but isn't I would fix that for sure.

As usual it depends on the case, as with most things in life :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons' [lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) libraries provide a way to handle null values

the method [defaultIfNull](http://goo.gl/45Kkv) in the class [ObjectUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html) enables you to return a default value if the object passed is null

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use the Optional type, unless it truly is optional, often the exit is better handled as an exception, unless you were truly were expecting null as an option, and not because you regularly write buggy code.
2. The problem is not null as a type it has its uses, as Google's article points out. The problem is that nulls should be checked and handled, often they can be exited gracefully.
3. There are a number of null cases that represent invalid conditions in areas outside the routine operation of the program (invalid user input, database issues, network failure, missing files, corrupt data), which is what checked exceptions are for, handling them, even if it's just to log it.
4. Exception handling is permitted different operational priorities and privileges in the JVM as opposed to a type, like Optional, that makes sense for the exceptional nature of their occurrence, including early support for prioritized lazy loading of the handler into memory, since you don't need it hanging around all the time.
5. You don't need to write null handlers all over the place, only where they are likely to occur, anywhere you are potentially accessing unreliable data service, and since most of these fall into few general patterns that can easily be abstracted you really only need a handler call, except in rare cases.

So I guess my answer would be wrap it in a checked exception and handle it, or fix the unreliable code if it's within your capability.