# Recommended value to pass instead of String parameter for a method in java

Tags: java, clean-code, method-overloading

We have a method called **attachDevice(Device device)** which has only one argument. We had a situation to overload this method with one more parameter  as like **attachDevice(Device device, String deviceName)**.

***with single argument***

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    ..
    ..        
}
```

---

***with double arguments***

```
public void attachDevice(Device device, String deviceName)
{
    ..
    device.setName(deviceName);
    genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    ..
}
```

Actually, my Team Lead asked me to make these two methods into a single generic call. The overloaded method only have two additional lines than the single method (which are shown as above). I can pass empty string instead of passing the deviceName, because the invocation of overloaded method will be very lesser than the invocation single argument call. But how bad it is that if passing null value since i don't set the name if the argument will be null. Which would be the best practice for this scenario?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**Note:** The actual problem I stated here is, that

**i)** I wanted to merge overloaded methods into one method which should be generic to avoid code duplication

**ii)** Need a recommended value to pass to the method (either empty string or null value) to stick with best coding practices.

**From the given answers, I got the best solution for my problem.** The [linked question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/) which has been referred this question duplicate also provides info about handling null value, but not covered the first point I mentioned in the note. And I didn't write bad code by passing null as parameter, since I am aware that NPE will thrown sometimes.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to handle nulls in Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/best-way-to-handle-nulls-in-java)

Comment: mutating the device argument seems like a poor design choice in the first place, why would attching a device change the name of the dvice im attaching?

Comment: **@jk**, We have a such scenario that, device name can be set by default programmatically when it boots up or it can be set by getting the input from user.

Comment: If the user can change device name you will need to be very careful about using device name as a key in a map

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely correct and that has been taken care of.

Comment: Anyone can make mistakes and learn, so as any team lead.

Comment: I agree with @jk. I assume the user can only set the device name once (cannot change it thereafter). If so, why not instantiate the `Device` along with its name (if given), only after the user has already decided whether to choose a name? That should be done before passing the instance to `attachDevice`. The purpose/usage of `genericDeviceMap` is also unclear, and the implications of not adding a nameless device to it.

Comment: @kelvin, In this context, the device is a network  component  which can be added or removed in a network whenever the user wants to. This has been performed in the attachDevice method. The genericDeviceMap which holds all the devices attached in the network. The default device name is MacAddress of a device. If user wants to change the name they can use overloaded method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would discourage you to ever use `null` since it can lead to a further NPE, which are hard to debug (and cost a lot if they occur in production code).

## Solution 1 (overload method)

If no `deviceName` is provided, you can provide a default one instead. The biggest disadvantage from this approach is the danger in `genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device)` because it can silently override the entry whose key is the default name (therefore, losing track of the previous `Device`).

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    attachDevice(device, "DefaultName");       
}

public void attachDevice(Device device, String deviceName)
{
    ..
    device.setName(deviceName);
    genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    ..
}
```

## Solution 2 (extract method)

Maybe that with your current architecture it doesn't make sense to add an entry to `genericDeviceMap` when `attachDevice` is called without a name. If so, a good approach is to only extract the common behaviour between the two `attachDevice` into private methods. I personnally don't like this approach for 2 reasons:

- The behaviour between the two `attachDevice` is not the same, one has a side-effect (`device.setName(deviceName)`) and the other not
- The side-effect in itself who often lead to subtle bugs because you alter an object who's coming from an outside scope

Code:

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    preAttachDevice();
    postAttachDevice();      
}

public void attachDevice(Device device, String deviceName)
{
    preAttachDevice();
    device.setName(deviceName);
    genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    postAttachDevice();
}

private void preAttachDevice()
{
    ...
}

private void postAttachDevice()
{
    ...
}
```

## Solution 3 (remove method)

My favorite, but the hardest. Ask yourself if you really need these two methods ? Does it make really sense to be able to call `attachDevice` either with a name or not ? Shouldn't you be able to say that `attachDevice` **must** be called with a name ?

In this case the code is simplified to only one method

```
public void attachDevice(Device device, String deviceName)
{
    ..
    device.setName(deviceName);
    genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    ..
}
```

Or on the other hand, do you really need to maintain a `Map` of devices and devices names and set the device's name ? If not, you can get rid of the second method and only keep the first one.

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    ...
    ...     
}
```

Comment: **@Spotted**, I know using null would be awkward thing, but the app has been designed such way to make things bit complicated. I'll pick up the 1st approach as solution for the current scenario. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that your team leader is asking you to create bad code. Having to pass some arbitrary value in as a name parameter when you do not want to specify a name is messy and confusing for any devs looking to use the method.

Instead, keep your two methods (though I'd rename your latter one to something like `attachNamedDevice` to make it clear it does something different to `attachDevice`, then move the common code into private methods:

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    preDeviceNameSetup(device);
    postDeviceNameSetup(device);        
}

public void attachNamedDevice(Device device, String deviceName)
{
    preDeviceNameSetup(device);
    device.setName(deviceName);
    genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    postDeviceNameSetup(device);        
}

private void preDeviceNameSetup(Device device)
{
    ...
}

private void postDeviceNameSetup(Device device)
{
    ...
}
```

That way, you keep the API clean, but avoid code duplication in the implementation.

Comment: I do prefer that solution, since with an overloaded methods you don't necessarily know that different arguments produce different behaviour. If I have a Device that has a name and call `attachDevice(Device)` then that name can possibly get nuked. Or not - who knows. Hard to tell. If course that method _could_ just call `attachDevice(device, device.hasName() ? device.getName() : "Default name")` (ore equivalent) but then it seems like the two methods are still redundant. `attachNamedDevice` more clearly marks it as separate.

Comment: A problem with requiring that public API calls use two separate methods is that it compels code duplication in derived or wrapper classes.  If one exposes a `static final` string `YourClassName.nameNotSpecified` and the a courtesy overload which is `final` and is documented as chaining to the normal one while passing that string, then derived classes or wrapper classes will have a single point of attachment.

Comment: @vld, if user want to update the name, that can be done using the overloaded methods. We have rest api call to invoke these methods based on the input from user.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Remove the second function with the String as second parameter.
2. Call `device.setName(deviceName)` before calling `attachDevice(device)`. It is not the responsibility of the `attachDevice` method to set the name of the device.
3. Change the `attachDevice` method to add the device to the `genericDeviceMap` if it has a name, as shown in the code snippet below.

If you also need to add the device to the `genericDeviceMap` when it does not have a name, you are probably better off setting such a default in the constructor of the `Device` class itself or something like that.

```
public void attachDevice(Device device)
{
    // ...
    if (device.getName())
    {
        genericDeviceMap.put(deviceName, device);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This keeps your concerns separated and helps you stay away from functions with side effects.