# Should I handle a null value passed into a method inside the method or from the caller?

Tags: java

Say I have a method like so:

```
public boolean extract(String string)
{
  // return true if string can be extracted, false otherwise
}
```

And a caller

```
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(myString))
{
boolean isExtracted = extract(myString);
}
// do something else
```

Does it make more sense to move checking the string is empty or null inside the method? What is the best practice here?

Comment: Always make things easy for the consumer -- if necessary, at the expense of implementation (here of `extract`).  We want our abstractions to be useful as well as simple to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to handle nulls in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51076/best-way-to-handle-nulls-in-java)

Comment: The bigger question I have is what does the caller do in place of `// do something else`?

Comment: What does `extract` do when presented with a blank string? Does it have generally undesirable behaviour (e.g. crash or null pointer exception) or does the function handle it properly but with a result that is not useful for this particular call site?

Comment: You have received a number of downvotes likely because your question provides too little background and is asking about best practices. I suggest retracting the question and asking it again with more background as to what you are specifically attempting to achieve. You can see from the answers you have received that people need more information in order to provide you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most useful principles in object oriented programming is the Tell-don’t-Ask principle.

In short it remembers us to tell an object what to do and let the object itself do the validation, instead of asking an object it’s state and have the caller do the validation. The caller shouldn’t have knowledge on the inner workings of the method it calls.

So in your example, the null-check should be handled inside the method, but then the ‘extract’ method itself also seems to violate the Tell-don’t-Ask principle. The method is probably called before another operation on the same object, if so, the extract method can be made private and called from the method that *really* does the work.

In case the extract method *is* the method that does the work, it violates the CQS principle, by returning a bool. That principle is really useful too, because we can get a quick idea of what a method does by looking at it’s signature. If it returns something, it’s a query, otherwise a command. The name of your extract method sounds like a command, but the signature looks like a query.